# How to output a csv file and XML file from a pyspark dataframe with multiple columns having same name?

Tags: xml, dataframe, csv, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like shown below:

| ID | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd123 | efgh456 | ijkl789 | mnop012 |

I got a requirement to convert this dataframe to a csv file from databricks and an XML file such that all column names are same like below.

| ID | value | value | value | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd123 | efgh456 | ijkl789 | mnop012 |

Maybe I could output 3 columns with same name by changing datatypes to String, Char, Varchar respectively. But there are 4 columns now.

This is xml sample:

```
<actions>
    <action>
      <action_type>create</action_type>
      <profile>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <value>abcd123</value>
        <value>efgh456</value>
        <value>ijkl789</value>
        <value>mnop012</value>
      </profile>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default spark won't allow to create a `csv file with duplicate column names`.

But we can do a workaround for this case by introducing required column names as a new line in the data then write as `csv` file **`without header`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2, 3,4,5]], ['id','value_1','value_2','value_3','value_4'])

#header line as data
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([['id','value','value','value','value']])

#union all the data and write as csv
df1.unionAll(df).repartition(1).write.\
mode("overwrite").option("header",False).\
csv("<path_to_dir>")
```

---

**`Print the file contents:`**

```
print(dbutils.fs.head("<path_to_dir>"))
#id,value,value,value,value
#1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: It worked for generating the CSV file, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PySpark/Spark, so I can only recommend going from your spark dataframe directly to an intermediate CSV, then using plain Python to coerce that into the CSV and XML you need.

Assuming you can get an input.csv like (using `df.write.csv(...)`):

```
ID,value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4
1,abcd123,efgh456,ijkl789,mnop012
```

Read the CSV and save the rows to a list (discarding the header, if it exists):

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # discard header
    rows = list(reader)
```

Then write rows back out with the correct header:

```py
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["ID"] + ["value"] * len(rows[0][1:]))
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

That gives me:

```
ID,value,value,value,value
1,abcd123,efgh456,ijkl789,mnop012
```

That assumes the first column is your ID, then it just writes a "value" column for every other column in the input after ID.

Python's xml.etree.ElementTree will build the XML you need using the rows list again, from the top-down, starting with the root "actions" element:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("actions")
for row in rows:
    action = ET.SubElement(root, "action")

    action_type = ET.SubElement(action, "action_type")
    action_type.text = "create"

    profile = ET.SubElement(action, "profile")

    id_ = ET.SubElement(profile, "id")
    id_.text = row[0]

    for x in row[1:]:
        value = ET.SubElement(profile, "value")
        value.text = x

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree)
tree.write("output.xml")
```

Again, it assumes the first column is ID and every column after should be "value".  That gives me:

```xml
<actions>
  <action>
    <action_type>create</action_type>
    <profile>
      <id>1</id>
      <value>abcd123</value>
      <value>efgh456</value>
      <value>ijkl789</value>
      <value>mnop012</value>
    </profile>
  </action>
</actions>
```